# use where after mergeBingings

Tags: laravel

```
$query1 = $this->trainer->login()
            ->join('lessons', 'lessons.trainer_id', '=', 'trainers.id')
            ->join('player_lessons', 'player_lessons.lesson_id', '=', 'lessons.id')
            ->select('trainers.*', DB::raw('count(' . DB::raw('DISTINCT(player_lessons.player_id)') . ') as num'))
            ->whereDate('lessons.start_time', '>=', $start)
            ->whereDate('lessons.start_time', '<=', $end) 
            ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($start, $end) {                    
                $query->whereDate('lessons.end_time', '>=', $start)
                      ->whereDate('lessons.end_time', '<=', $end);
            })
            ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($start, $end) {
                $query->whereDate('lessons.start_time', '<', $start)
                      ->whereDate('lessons.end_time', '>', $end);
            })                                    
            ->groupBy('trainers.id');        
    $query2 = $this->trainer->login()
            ->leftJoin('lessons', 'lessons.trainer_id', '=', 'trainers.id')
            ->leftJoin('player_lessons', 'player_lessons.lesson_id', '=', 'lessons.id')
            ->selectRaw('trainers.* , IF(count(player_lessons.player_id) = NULL , 0, 0) as num')
            ->whereNotIn('trainers.id', $query1->pluck('trainers.id'))
            ->groupBy('trainers.id')
            ->union($query1)
            ->orderBy('id', 'ASC');
$list = DB::table( DB::raw("({$query2->toSql()}) as list") )
            ->mergeBindings($query2->getQuery())
            ->select('list.*')
```

how do i use where() after mergebinding. i wrote like dd($list->where('name','like','%abc%') but it didn't show any record event i have correct record please help

SR FOR MY ENGLISH

Answer (score 0):

Use Eloquent Model, you can create common model here is an example:

```
      $query = Common::query()
                ->from(DB::raw('(' . $query2->toSql() . ') list'))//select from sub Query
                ->mergeBindings($query2->getQuery())
->where('col','val');
```